# How to convert soap response to string in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap-client, webservicetemplate

I am using WebServiceTemplate to consume SOAP response. For logging purpose i need to get the SOAP response in string. 
For example , `"<envelope><body><name>xyz</name></body></envelope>"`

Comment: Are you familiar with [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)?

Comment: No VGR, I am new to SOAP web service. yet to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive it like below with WebServiceTemplate:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream  bytArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bytArrayOutputStream);
wsTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(defautUri, source, result); 
final String reply = new String(bytArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())
```

Answer (score -1):

If you using spring, you can add log using log4j in interceptor. Log4j can write to file or even db. I hope its help you.

Comment: Yes but here major part is convert that soap response received in Java object to XML string as I mentioned above.